# Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, jndi

I'm trying to perform basic MySQL database connection in my Spring web app. With everything configured just like in tutorial I'm learning from, I get following console output:

```
08-Aug-2016 21:39:32.244 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
08-Aug-2016 21:39:32.248 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
08-Aug-2016 21:39:32.254 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
08-Aug-2016 21:39:32.255 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductDao' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductDao' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
08-Aug-2016 21:39:32.257 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productsController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductDao' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setProductDao' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency [javax.sql.DataSource]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/spring] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

Here's my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/drewnostalDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/config/dao-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/config/service-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And dao-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.drewnostal.dao"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/spring" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

</beans>
```

And here's context.xml from Tomcat config folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/drewnostalDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="root" password="" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"/>

</Context>
```

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.4 and java 8. Spring jars version is 4.3.1 and mysql-connector-java version is 6.0.3

Comment: There is a mismatch betwen jndi name in `context.xml` and `dao-context.xml`

Comment: Shouldn't that jndi-name "jdbc/spring" in you spring config file map to your resource? The resource name is "jdbc/drewnostalDB"

Comment: Wow, such a stupid mistake, thank you guys for these answers, it work now ;)